# How to set different status code for different type of Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to handle Exception in spring boot Application using `@ControllerAdvice`. I don't want separate methods for each types of exception. I want to handle all types of exception using only one method with main class as `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)`

I tried like below it's handling exception properly but problem is that I also want to set different type of status code for different type of exception.

here I am getting `500` for every type of exception.

can any one tell me how to set different status code for different type of exception?

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RestExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public  ResponseEntity<Object>  handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex,WebRequest requset) {

            ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();                                   

            exceptionMessageObj.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            exceptionMessageObj.setMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());     
            exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());

            return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionMessageObj, new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get started by focusing from the last line of your code.

Comment: you are setting status code as `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` hence u r getting 500

Comment: what i need to change to get flexible status code with exception

Answer (score 5):

There's a different Spring approach that you can also do. Note that it doesn't work with native Java exceptions (as you need to add an annotation to the Exception class definition), which may or may not be acceptable to you.

1. Define custom exceptions for the status codes you want to surface (or reuse existing ones from your current business logic).
2. Add [`@ResponseStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) to the top of each of these exceptions.
3. In your controllers, only throw these exceptions.

This way, you don't need to do any type checking of the exceptions. You don't even need to define your own `@ControllerAdvice`. Spring will handle surfacing the correct HTTP status code. If you do choose to still implement your `@ControllerAdvice` with this method, you can use the annotation to grab the correct status code with:

```
import static org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation

HttpStatus resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(Exception exception) {
    ResponseStatus annotation = findMergedAnnotation(exception.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class);
    if (annotation != null) {
        return annotation.value();
    }
    return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
}
```

<sub>(Annotation resolution method originally posted [here](http://blog.sizovs.net/spring-rest-exception-handler/))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You may check what instance is your exception of and return accordingly:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 public ResponseEntity < Object > handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex, WebRequest requset) {

  if (ex instanceof MyCustomException1) {
   // Return error code 500
  } else {
   // return error code 404
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set different status code as per type of Exception.

```
HttpStatus statuscode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

if(ex instanceof ExceptionClass1){
   statuscode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
}else if(ex instanceof ExceptionClass2){
  statuscode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd question your needs first. Why do you want to have all exception handling in one place?

It's in the contrary with the other need - to have response code configurable.

you have two options:

- create a nasty if/else switch containing your exception instanceofs
- don't handle everything in one method

I prefer the latter one and if u're afraid that your code will be duplicated - please take a look below:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(YourException1.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> handleYourException1(YourException1 ex, WebRequest requset) {
        return commonHandler(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex, requset);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> commonHandler(HttpStatus status, Exception ex, WebRequest requset) {
        ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();

        exceptionMessageObj.setStatus(status.value());
        exceptionMessageObj.setMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionMessageObj, status);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain why handleYourException1 need annotation @ExceptionHandler, but  commonHandler doesn't?

Comment: @BabyishTank coz the common one is called internally by the annotated method, it's supposed to show some code reusability in case you want to handle multiple exceptions in a similar fashion

Answer (score 0):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {
        log.error("IOException: " + e.getMessage());

        final Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put("message", "Something went wrong...");

        // My custom IOException handler :)
        if (e instanceof IOException) {
            return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(message);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch statement and create multiple cases:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(new DescriptionInErrorResponse());
    errorResponse.getError().setText(ex.getMessage());

    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;

    if (ex instanceof CustomException) {
        switch (((CustomException) ex).getCode()) {
            case BAD_REQUEST:
                errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST.getName());
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                break;
            case NOT_FOUND:
                errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.NOT_FOUND.getName());
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
                break;
            case METHOD_ARGUMENT_NOT_VALID:
                errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.METHOD_ARGUMENT_NOT_VALID.getName());
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                break;

            default:
                errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.UNKNOWN.getName());
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;
                break;
        }
    } else if (ex instanceof ConstraintViolationException
            || ex instanceof javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException) {
        errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST.getName());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    } else if (ex instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException) {
        errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.METHOD_ARGUMENT_NOT_VALID.getName());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

    } else if (ex instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException) {
        errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getName());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    } else if (ex instanceof HttpMessageNotReadableException) {
        errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST.getName());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    } else if (ex instanceof ServletRequestBindingException){
        errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST.getName());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }
    else {

        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        errorResponse.getError().setCode(ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getName());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus).body(errorResponse);
}
```